# Slow query SELECT ... GROUP BY on two tables fields` (MySQL/InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, performance, select, group-by

I have a query to select orders, and for each order I need to get list of products it includes with summary quantity for each product.

**Currently it's very slow (10 seconds on my setup), I need to speed it up.**

**Update: switching over to MyISAM is not an option, I need transactions**

The query currently is like that:

```sql
SELECT `Order`.*, `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`msrp`, SUM(`OrderItem`.`quantity`) AS sum
FROM `orders` AS `Order` 
LEFT JOIN `order_items` AS `OrderItem` ON (`OrderItem`.`order_id` = `Order`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `product_variations` AS `ProductVariation` ON (`OrderItem`.`product_variation_id` = `ProductVariation`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `Product` ON (`ProductVariation`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`)
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY `Order`.`id`, `Product`.`id`
ORDER BY `Order`.`created` DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Explain :

[image: explain results]

Schema (truncated, only required fields left):

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customer_comments` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `id_created` (`id`,`created`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_variation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('First','Second') default NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_UNIQUE` (`order_id`,`product_variation_id`,`type`),
  KEY `fk_order_items_product_variations1` (`product_variation_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_items_orders1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_items_product_variations1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_variation_id`) REFERENCES `product_variations` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `product_variations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_variations_products1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `msrp` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Server is MySQL 5.0.77, tables are InnoDB. 
`orders` is about 75k records, `order_items` 160k records, `product_variations` 140k records, `product` - 300 records.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try would be to replace `SUM` with a precomputed product_sum table. InnoDB is known to be slower with aggregate functions (especially with 75k+ rows!). You really don't want to be computing this sum every query (unless the data is changes very often).

It might be helpful to use a trigger that recomputes the product_sum table after an insert/update to orders .. but it's not really clear what the context of this query is (is it run by the end user? is it a web request or a report? etc).

Another option is to switch the engine to MyISAM (which is much faster with aggregates), however a huge negative there is you lose transactions and foreign key constraints.

Comment: I held precomputing sums and other aggregates as a last resort. My understanding was that if RDBMS is good at something - that's filtering, grouping and aggregates. I could of course precompute all the aggregates, by why use RDBMS at all then?

Comment: Regarding context - it's web interface pagination query; (actually a part of it - I need to sum up one more time for each `order` - not sure how to do that yet as WITH ROLLUP doesn't work on this query).

Comment: The problem here isnt the RDBMS, it's the table engine. Switch over to MyISAM just as a test to see if aggregates are indeed the bottleneck. InnoDB reads every row when aggregating, MyISAM doesn't. So unfortunately if you want InnoDB's transaction/constraint features, you have to cache the aggregations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Although your query appears well structured and joined together, the volume of records may be the issue.  You have group by in place, etc.  I would add ONE clause...

SELECT STAIGHT_JOIN  ... rest of query.

The STRAIGHT_JOIN tells the engine to do it in the order you've stated instead of it trying to optimize the smaller tables as the primary, then joining in some reversed order of intent.  I've seen STRAIGHT_JOIN work amazing performance in SEVERAL other areas... maybe it can help yours too.

Comment: Unfortunately, not on this one. Tried it - no significant difference.